# Smart pointers which ambiguously point to a heap or stack object

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

One of my applications would greatly benefit from a variant of `std::unique_ptr<T>` which could be configured to not always assume ownership of the object being pointed to.

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
class AbstractFoo { ... };

template<typename T> Foo : public AbstractFoo 
{
    Foo( const AbstractFoo& absFoo ) { ... } 
    ... 
};
```

and an API which standardizes upon every routine accepting an `AbstractFoo` and converting to particular instances of `Foo<T>` as necessary. In cases where the reference to an `AbstractFoo` is actually already an instance of the proper derived type, only a `dynamic_cast` is required and no data need be copied. However, when the abstract reference is of the improper type, non-trivial work needs to be performed to create a copy in the requested format.

My desired interface would look as follows:

```
template<typename T>
my_unique_ptr<Foo<T>> Convert( AbstractFoo& absFoo )
{
    if( Foo<T>* foo = dynamic_cast<Foo<T>*>(&absFoo) )
        return my_unique_ptr<Foo<T>>( foo, false );
    else
        return my_unique_ptr<Foo<T>>( new Foo<T>(absFoo) );
}

void Bar( AbstractFoo& absFoo )
{
    my_unique_ptr<Foo<T>> ptr = Convert<T>( absFoo );
    ...
}
```

where the class `make_unique_ptr<T>` has a constructor similar to `std::unique_ptr<T>`, but with an optional boolean argument which specifies whether or not the pointer should be owned by the smart pointer or not.

Is there a best practice solution for such a situation? I would prefer to avoid returning a raw pointer since it may lead to memory leaks if an exception is thrown before an object is manually deleted.

Comment: Would `shared_ptr` work? (you'd either need `AbstractFoo` to implement `enable_shared_from_this` or pass a `shared_ptr` to `Convert` instead of a reference).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be a case for `shared_ptr`, which does exactly what you said: doesn't always assume ownership, and behaves accordingly. Your boolean flag has an implicit equivalent in `shared_ptr`'s reference counter. Other possibility is to always clone the object even if the type is right, but perhaps provide a method for cheap&fast cloning if possible.

Comment: @dlf According to [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), both of your suggested approaches require the object to be already managed by a `shared_ptr`. This is unfortunately extremely intrusive and I had hoped that the usage of smart pointers would be limited to within my implementations of the library.

Comment: @BartoszKP I am unsure of how to manipulate the reference count of `shared_ptr` to accomplish the goal. Would you mind expanding upon your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @JackPoulson Yes, that is true. If that's a deal-breaker, you'll need something else (such as BartoszKP's suggestion of always creating a clone, but making cloning cheap).

Comment: @BartoszKP My current approach actually does involve cloning, but the issue is that it greatly limits what modifications I can make to the input object without (sometimes unnecessarily) requiring a deep copy. This is the reason that I would like to switch from a clone to a (smart) pointer.

Comment: what about using a smart pointer with an empty deleter?

Comment: @JackPoulson That was not a suggestion, just an analogy, a side note :) In case of `shared_ptr` nothing would have to be done, the reference counter just works in a way analogous (but more general) to your boolean flag.

Comment: @JackPoulson Fortunately no--the deleter is just an injected function rather than a template parameter. That fact makes all sorts of interesting things possible.

Comment: @JackPoulson i'm not sure about unique_ptr but shared_ptr has the same type, only the constructor is templated.

Comment: @programmerjake Sorry for the confusion, you both responded just as I realized my error and deleted my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of `shared_ptr` in conjunction with a custom deleter:

```
template<typename T>
shared_ptr<Foo<T>> Convert( AbstractFoo& absFoo )
{
    if( Foo<T>* foo = dynamic_cast<Foo<T>*>(&absFoo) )
        return shared_ptr<Foo<T>>( foo, [](Foo<T>*){} ); // do-nothing deleter
    else
        return make_shared<Foo<T>>( absFoo ); // regular deleter
}
```

Update: programmerjake evidently wrote the same idea in a comment while I was typing this. If you want to write it as an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: It will only leak if the code fails to delete the original `AbstractFoo&` that was passed to `Convert`, which would have been true before too. Otherwise, the reference count will go up and down as usual until it reaches 0, at which point...nothing will happen. :)

Comment: @BartoszKP no, the returned object would have the same lifetime as the argument

Answer (score 2):

I think this design is <strike>broken</strike> brittle:

> ```
> template<typename T>
> my_unique_ptr<Foo<T>> Convert( AbstractFoo& absFoo )
> {
>     if( Foo<T>* foo = dynamic_cast<Foo<T>*>(absFoo) )
>         return my_unique_ptr<Foo<T>>( foo, false );
>     else
>         return my_unique_ptr<Foo<T>>( new Foo<T>(absFoo) );
> }
> ```

In the `if` path, you create an object that *is tied to the lifetime* of the `absFoo` argument.

In the `else` path you create an object that is not tied to the lifetime of any other object.

The caller cannot distinguish between the two cases - this seems rather brittle.

---

As for still using it (with `shared_ptr` like [dlf suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25333831/321013)) ... 
Maybe `Convert` could be called `smart_foo_cast` or somesuch, then the lifetime thing would be imho better evident in its name.

Personally, I would also have it take an `AbstractFoo*` (that change would not affect the external API). Just make sure to *never* have it take a `const AbstractFoo&`, as you never know when a `const&` might be an implicit temporary.

---

Your problem would go away if you can either (optionally) "sink" the argument by using a `unique_ptr` as arg, or "share" the argument.

```
// Caller always yields ownership of absFoo:
template<typename T>
unique_ptr<Foo<T>> Convert( unique_ptr<AbstractFoo> absFoo );

// Caller may yield ownership of absFoo:
// (Caller needs to check whether absFoo was moved-from)
template<typename T>
unique_ptr<Foo<T>> Convert( unique_ptr<AbstractFoo>& absFoo );

// Caller may share ownership of absFoo with return value:
template<typename T>
shared_ptr<Foo<T>> Convert( const shared_ptr<AbstractFoo>& absFoo );
```

Comment: The `Convert` function is only a utility function meant for internal usage in the library. Requiring the input to be wrapped with a smart pointer has external effects.

Comment: Also, you raise a good point about not accepting a const reference input, and so I have modified [the interface in the actual project](https://github.com/elemental/Elemental/blob/531ea0d03e09b46c657c2c0053923202d2a42aab/src/core/Proxy.cpp) to accept pointers.